# .Net Core 3.1 Remove Schema on Swagger UI

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I have .Net 3.1 Web Api, I would like to remove this sections "Schemas" on Swagger UI.
How to do it?
[image: .net]

Comment: add this property in your Swagger UI Options `defaultModelsExpandDepth: -1` for hide schema section and for more reference refer this https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/#display

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: Can you please add your swagger ui configuration settings in your question.

Comment: @Herman how did you fix this? I used the filter but I have red errors and I even opened a new topic as I want to get a fix on this!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

No need for a schema filter. After busting on it for days I have found out:

All needs to be done is in

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.DefaultModelsExpandDepth(-1);
});
```

Note: It is DefaultModels (plural) not DefaultModel (singular). Difference is *DefaultModels* is the default expansion depth for the model on the model-example section, whereas *DefaultModels* is the expansion depth for models.

Comment: Note that this will only hide the schemas section on swagger GUI. All of the schemas will still be there in the resulting json file.

Answer (score 13):

On Adding Swagger UI just add the following line:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
    c.DefaultModelsExpandDepth(-1);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

After a lot of breaking my head, using the user's suggestion "CoffeeCodeConverterImpl" I made the class like this:

```
public class RemoveSchemasFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        
        IDictionary<string, OpenApiSchema> _remove = swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, OpenApiSchema> _item in _remove)
        {
            swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Remove(_item.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
 c.DocumentFilter<RemoveSchemasFilter>();
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked fine but errors appear on top. I have even created a post on your proposed fix. Can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64387797/remove-schema-on-swagger-ui-continued

Comment: You could also just do it like this: `swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Clear();`
Note that clearing all the schemas will probably result in swagger GUI errors, like @grozdeto already pointed out

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom `IDocumentFilter` implementation to your swagger configuration:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options => options.DocumentFilter<RemoveSchemasFilter>());
```

In the `Apply` method of `RemoveSchemasFilter` you should then be able to identify the elements of the `OpenApiDocument` you want to remove and do so accordingly.

Comment: Could you explain how to implement it?