# Remove Schema on Swagger UI -continued

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I have followed the top article : [.Net Core 3.1 Remove Schema on Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62858580/net-core-3-1-remove-schema-on-swagger-ui)

I applied this filter:

```
public class RemoveSchemasFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        
        IDictionary<string, OpenApiSchema> _remove = swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, OpenApiSchema> _item in _remove)
        {
            swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Remove(_item.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

I have added it here:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.OperationFilter<AddRequiredHeaderParameter>(Configuration.GetSection("DefaultConfig")["TenantId"]);
                options.DocumentFilter<RemoveSchemasFilter>();
             }
```

All good Schema is removed from the bottom of Swagger UI. However, when I click on a method it brings a dialogue of errors. It works but this windows stays on top and it is very annoying.

[image]

Let's solve this problem together as it was unsolved previously!

Answer (score 1):

The schema filter is useless.

All needs to be done is in

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.DefaultModelsExpandDepth(-1);
}
```

Note: It is Default Models not Default Model. DIfference is DefaultModel is the default expansion depth for the model on the model-example section, whereas DefaultModels is the expansion depth for models.

Comment: Downvote for saying it is "useless". It is very useful since it worked for me when your solution did not.

Comment: Want to add to this that this option seems great except if you are already mapping the endpoint as an option, you can't map a second option for DefaultModelsExpandDepth in the same call. If you do a second app.UseSwaggerUI call with this overload, it will ignore the first one since it uses a singleton (https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1996). I'm still struggling with using the other overload, as I haven't seen the syntax for doing DefaultModelsExpandDepth with that one